# Chrome position fixed breaking with 3d transforms

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform

I basically have a fixed header and a content area with lots of 3d transforms using Isotope

```
<header style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0">
</header>

<div class="isotope">
   // 3d transforms happen here
</div>
```

I have a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/jzT2L/3/

The fiddle looks okay, but if you copy the 'result' html from the iframe and run as a document in Chrome/Canary, then you will see the issue.

It also helps if you enable "Composited render layer borders" under chrome://flags/

Basically when you scroll and the fixed header is over a 3d layer, chrome also makes it a 3d layer and breaks the style/layout[image: notice how the fixed header is now indented and has become a 3d layer]

Notice how the fixed header is now indented and has become a 3d layer

The same works fine in FF, IE etc. Is this a known bug and what can I do to stop this happening?

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? Running 28.0.1500.71 and have no problem with is.

Comment: Im running version 28.0.1500.72.  Others have also said they don't get issues which makes me think it group be a GPU/driver issue?

Comment: I also did not see any issues and I'm running 28.0.1500.95

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the following style on the container of the 'broken' elements:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```